# How to match as many as possible in group?

Tags: regular-expression

I have a question about vim regexp, How can I match as many as possible in a iterm group?

ther string is `op    test` or `op test` or `optest`, I want to match `test`, my expr is `\(op\s*\)\@<=[^ ]*`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [`\zs`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html?#%2F%5Czs) marker for the start of the captured match. That way you don't need to deal with zero matches and you can drop at least one grouped expression.

If you want to match `test` in `optest` or `op test`, then you can use:

```
op\s*\zstest
```

If you want to match any words (not just `test`) coming after `op`, then use:

```
op\s*\zs\w*
```

(Or use `\S` instead of `\w` if you want to match any non-blank characters and not just keyword characters.)